# Projection in decentralized graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, projection, simplex

I have a graph of $N$ nodes that are collaboratively solving an optimization problem.
Each node $n$ has a scalar variable $\lambda_n \geq 0, \forall n$ updated at every iteration.

At the end of each iteration, I would like to project the vector $\lambda = [\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n]$ into the simplex, i.e. $\lambda$ needs to satisfy
$$ \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i = 1$$
Is there a way to perform this step? The issue I'm facing is that to be able to do so, I need to have all the values of $\lambda_n$ in one place to be able to do the projection.

Comment: What do you mean by "project"? normalize by the sum? Check if the point is inside or outside?

Comment: @user619894: I need the sum of $\lambda$ to be equal to one.

Comment: Maybe add a Lagrange multiplier somehow?

Comment: Is it possible to explain further your point?

Comment: you need to add the constraint that $\sum \lambda = 1$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier